# Can iptables relate the physical wireguard UDP connection to the tunneled TCP session?

Tags: iptables, wireguard, conntrack

I'm locking down the egress of my Linux box, making OUTPUT chain default deny.

My wireguard peers are from the subnet `10.1.0.0/16`. Originally I thought I can just `-A OUTPUT -d 10.1.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT`, and while that is needed, it is not sufficient in itself.

As confirmed by tracing, the physical UDP connection to the wireguard peer also needs allowing, which makes sense on second thought.

Now, I could go on and manually allow the wireguard port of the peer endpoints. But I wonder if there's some more automatic mechanism, that would relate the physical UDP packets to the already allowed tunnel packet, and automatically allow it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WireGuard provides the means to handle this with *iptables*: by setting a firewall mark on the outgoing envelope packets. This is available through the low level [`wg`](https://manpages.debian.org/wireguard-tools/wg.8#CONFIGURATION_FILE_FORMAT) command and thus also available with `wg-quick`:

> - FwMark — a 32-bit fwmark **for outgoing packets**. If set to 0 or "off", this option is disabled. May be specified in hexadecimal by prepending
>   "0x". Optional.

[`wg-quick` provides an example](https://manpages.debian.org/wireguard-tools/wg-quick.8#EXAMPLES) to be used in `PostUp`:

> Building on the last example, one might attempt the so-called
> ``kill-switch'', in order to prevent the flow of unencrypted packets
> through the non-WireGuard interfaces, by adding the following two
> lines `PostUp` and `PreDown` lines to the `[Interface]` section:
>
> ```ini
> PostUp = iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
> PreDown = iptables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
> ```

For this problem's use case (which has an inverted logic since using a default drop policy and doesn't require to distinguish the local case) that would be something like this in the configuration file:

```ini
[Interface]
...
FwMark = 0xcafe # or any non-zero value
...

PostUp = iptables -A OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -j ACCEPT
PreDown = iptables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -j ACCEPT
```

Or this rule can be added outside of WireGuard's configuration, probably  using directly the WireGuard interface name (eg: `wg0`) instead of `%i` and the firewall mark value 0xcafe in the rule rather than querying the value from WireGuard.

If the peer roams, the rule will still be able to track it for outgoing envelope packets.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice answer! I pondered in the mean time, and with this solution, I would need to reason if some exploited service with NET_ADMIN capability would guess an (assumedly secret) tag and egress to some attacker-controlled server on the wireguard port. Well, thin chance, and without inside knowledge they would show up on monitoring before they guess the right tag.. and if they exploit so much, maybe they can get root anyway who knows... but since my WG config needs the peer IPs anyway (and the peers don't roam), I could as well add manual rules for them.

Answer (score 0):

If, by "physical UDP" you mean traffic to the peer outside of the VPN tunnel then, no. While it is possible to associate traffic on different ports to the same address via iptables (port-knocking is a good example) in this case, the traffic flows inside and outside the tunnel are going to different IP addresses.